# performSelectorOnMainThread strangeness

Tags: objective-c, multithreading, ios, ios4

just stuck with strange thing. I have the following code:

```
-(void)ImageDownloadCompleat
{
    [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(updateImageButton:) 
                           withObject:nil 
                        waitUntilDone:YES];
}

-(void)updateImageButton {
    NSLog(@"image OKEY");
    UIImage *img = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[NSString stringWithFormat:
                                                     @"%@/%@.jpg",pathPreview,self.idProducts]];
    //images.image = img;

    [images setBackgroundImage:img forState:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [img release];
}
```

and it crashes with Unrecognized selector sent to instance error. what's wrong with the code above?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Since your method was declared as

```
-(void)updateImageButton
```

the corresponding selector is `@selector(updateImageButton)` *without a trailing colon.* Change:

```
[self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(updateImageButton:) 
                       withObject:nil 
                    waitUntilDone:YES];
```

to

```
[self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(updateImageButton) 
                       withObject:nil 
                    waitUntilDone:YES];
```

and it should work.

Comment: thanks it did the trick.. but the background image for button is still not updated, though the image is created and really exists in file system... what am doing wrong?

Comment: @Adviser2010: you're setting the background image just for UIControlEventTouchUpInside, i.e. when a touch is released, inside the button. Is that what you wanted? You could do a quick NSLog(@"%@", img) to confirm that the thing is loaded, and you also shouldn't be releasing it because you don't have an owning reference.

Comment: no, i figured out that i was using wrong UIControlEvent... after applying right one - it works like charm

Comment: @Bavarious I don't think I would've ever figured out the colon thing.  +1 from me!